# Create an Interactable JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist

As many might know, components in a JList are not interactable (you can't interact with them) and they are just like snapshots from the component's appearance. I'm working on a simple application and JList is what I want, except that the components in the list should be interactable.

So far I've created this, by implementing a simple AbstractListModel, and ListCellRenderer:

[image: screenshot]

Each component in the JList is a JPanel, which as you can see contains other components like JProgressBar, JLable and JButton. The only problem is that the buttons (and all other components) are not interactable. How can I fix this ?

**NOTE:** I don't want a single column JTable!

Comment: Consider using a layout to generate a list of vertically aligned components instead, maybe VerticalLayout from SwingX or BoxLayout for example

Comment: @MadProgrammer I actually do have such a plan in mind just in case JList can't be fixed (using a JPanel with GridLayout is what I have). But I'll be waiting for an answer to this question.

Comment: I think you answered it yourself, `JList` is not editable, it was not designed to be and trying to retrofit to to be, is a LOT of hard work (and yes, I've actually tried). You "could" use a `MouseListener` on the `JList`, find the row that was clicked, translate the `MouseEvent` to be within the context of the `ListCellRenderer` and determine what was clicked...but the first option is quicker and simpler (using a layout manager)

Comment: @Seyed Mohammad I don't want a single column JTable! == wrong decision

Comment: @MadProgrammer If you have tried and there is no easy & clean fix for it, then it's decided! The answer simply is that it can't be done and I should go for alternatives. Post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you answered it yourself, `JList` is not editable, it was not designed to be and trying to retrofit it to be, is a LOT of hard work (and yes, I've actually tried).

You "could" use a `MouseListener` on the `JList`, find the row that was clicked, translate the `MouseEvent` to be within the context of the `ListCellRenderer`'s `Component` and try and determine what was clicked ... but, again this is a lot of additional work which can more easily be achieved through other means...

Consider using a layout to generate a list of vertically aligned components instead, maybe `VerticalLayout` from SwingX or `BoxLayout` for example

Answer (score 2):

Adding this answer for people in the future.
I just ran into the exact same problem, using `JList` and `ListCellRenderer` is wonderful if you only need custom rendered items, but not fully functional components.

This is what I did and works a treat:

```
panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

and then when I have the list of the information I need to dynamically assemble the panel:

```
public void build(List<Item> items){
    panel.removeAll();
    for(Item item: items){
        panel.add(new ItemEntry(item));
    }
}
```

wrap your panel in a `JScrollPane` and itll work just like before only all your controls will now function properly :).